# "Attempt to set a non-property list object...." NSMutableDictionary with custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom class called `ServerModule` which is a subclass of `NSObject`. I'm basically storing all of these `ServerModule`s with a key-value pair in an `NSMutableDictionary`. The dictionary is then stored in `NSUserDefaults`. I learned that `NSUserDefaults` only returns an immutable version of the object when it is accessed, so I changed my dictionary initialization to this:

```
_AllModules = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[_editServerModules objectForKey:@"AllModules"]]; //initialize a copy of AllModules dictionary
```

Now, I am simply trying to store a custom `ServerModule` object in this dictionary, and sync it. The following code attempts to do this:

```
//Create new ServerModule
        ServerModule* newServer = [[ServerModule alloc]initWithUUID];
        newServer.name = self.tf_name.text;
        newServer.ip = self.tf_ip.text;
        newServer.port = self.tf_port.text;
        newServer.username = self.tf_user.text;
        newServer.password = self.tf_pass.text;
        //Add the ServerModule to AllModules dictionary with the key of its identifier
        [_AllModules setObject:newServer forKey:newServer.identifier];
        [self updateData];
        [_editServerModules synchronize];
```

The identifier is a string which is set in the constructor of `ServerModule`. Here is the code for `updateData`.

```
[_editServerModules setObject:_AllModules forKey:@"AllModules"];
```

In case you are wondering, the object at `@"AllModules"` is initialized in the AppDelegate as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary* AllModules = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

Once again, here is the error I am getting when I try to save something:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
    "42E9EEA0-9051-4E2A-81EA-DC8FC5639C26" = "<ServerModule: 0x8ac4e50>";
} as an NSUserDefaults value for key AllModules
```

Thanks for any help!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only store property list types (array, data, string, number, date, dictionary) or urls in [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This means that everything, including any nested dictionary values, must be property list types. You'll want to implement the [`NSCoding`](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) protocol on your `ServerModule` object and then use [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to serialize your data before storing it and and [`NSKeyedUnarchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to deflate your data after reading it back out of [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example, given the properties you've shown exist on `ServerModule` objects, I'd add the following [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol methods to your `ServerModule` implementation:

```
#pragma mark - NSCoding support
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.ip forKey:@"ip"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.port forKey:@"port"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.username forKey:@"username"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.password forKey:@"password"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder {
    self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.ip = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ip"];
    self.port = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"port"];
    self.username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    self.password = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    return self;
}
```

And then of course you'll need to serialize:

```
NSData* archivedServerModules = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_AllModules];
[_editServerModules setObject:archivedServerModules forKey:@"AllModules"];
```

and deflate appropriately:

```
NSData* archivedServerModules = [_editServerModules objectForKey:@"AllModules"];
NSDictionary* serverModules = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedServerModules];
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Do I have to convert the `NSMutableDictionary` I'm storing them in, or the actual objects?

Comment: @Carpetfizz All objects stored in `NSUserDefaults` must be property-list types, including all nested NSDictionary or NSArray values, so yes, the actual objects as well.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I didn't know that the p-list rules applied to nested objects as well.