# NSDictionary with NSNumber to NSString mapping is non-property-list object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, property-list

Following code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:photoIdToPath forKey:@"photo_id_to_path"];
```

gives me the following error:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
417675729 = "/Users/k06a/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/21163736-DF6F-4E79-8196-6A966C81ED1B/Documents/417675729";
} as an NSUserDefaults value for key photo_id_to_path
```

Here is `photoIdToPath` dictionary content analysis from Xcode debug console:

```
(lldb) po photoIdToPath
{
    417675729 = "/Users/k06a/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/21163736-DF6F-4E79-8196-6A966C81ED1B/Documents/417675729";
}

(lldb) po [[[photoIdToPath allKeys] lastObject] class]
__NSCFNumber

(lldb) po [[[photoIdToPath allValues] lastObject] class]
NSPathStore2
```

So `NSPathStore2` is subclass of `NSString`, why this dictionary is not property list?

**UPDATE:**

Here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey: I found text:

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. See “What is a Property List?” in Property List Programming Guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753529/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-nsmutabledictionary-with-custom

Comment: your photoIdToPath is dictionary... change it to string

Comment: After setting your key to an NSString, try explicitly setting your value as an NSString rather than an NSPathStore2 and see if it saves.

Comment: @CharanGiri There is no need to change the dictionary to a string. Only the key needs to be updated from an `NSNumber` to an `NSString`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way you can save a dictionary to `NSUserDefaults` (or write the dictionary to a file as a plist), all keys MUST be `NSString` objects and all values must be valid plist objects.

In other words, you can't have keys that are `NSNumber` objects. Convert them to `NSString` if you need to write the dictionary to `NSUserDefaults`.

For details on this, see the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i). Specifically the section titled [What is a Property List?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303). There is a table showing the XML tags used. Under that table you will see this excerpt:

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects.

Comment: Can you provide link to reference about this?

Comment: +1. The error `Attempt to set a non-property-list object` explicitly states that the object is not compatible with property lists.

Comment: @Chris But the error isn't clear that the problem is because the key isn't an `NSString`. I know I've seen it in the docs somewhere but so far I can't find the reference.

Comment: @rmaddy true, the error is ambiguous. It is strange, however, that Apple's documentation says NSNumber should be a valid plist object https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_29

Comment: @Chris The values can be `NSNumber` but not the keys. I just found it. I'm going to update my answer with the link in a minute.

Comment: @k06a I've update my answer with the reference you need.